# Prove that x $\in y$ iff $\{x\}\subseteq y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

My goal is to prove that $x\in y$ iff $\{x\}\subseteq y$.

Here's my sketch of a proof:

We have $x\in y$, and by definition $A\subseteq B := \forall a$ ($a\in A \implies a \in B$). We may infer $\forall$$z$ ($z = x$ $\implies$ $x \in y$) and $\forall$z ($z = x$ $\iff$ $z \in {x}$), then $\forall$$z$ ($z \in \{ x\}$ $\implies$ $z \in y$). And i stopped here.

I'm pretty sure that there is a simpler way of writing this proof (and by simpler, i mean doing this demonstration without invoking first order logic formalizations of set theoretic definitions)

Comment: I updated some of your equations with proper TeX code. It would be helpful to your post if you correct the rest.

Comment: LOST (Language Of Set Theory), the most common formal set-theoretic "language" does not have "$\subseteq$" nor brace-brackets. These are brought in as abbreviations. $w=\{x\}$ means $\forall z\,(x\in w\iff z=x)$. So you can't really get any shorter or simpler than what you have done.

Comment: The unabbreviated version of what you want to prove is $\forall x\,\forall y\,(x\in y\iff \exists w\,((\forall z\,(z\in w\iff z=x))\land (\forall v(v\in w\implies v\in y))))$. Nobody actually writes like that.

Comment: In my 1st comment, "$x\in w$" should be "$z\in w$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks fine to me for the forward direction! If you want a proof in words instead of logical symbols:

- First suppose $x \in y$ and we want to show $\{x\} \subseteq y$. So fix any $z \in \{x\}$; by definition this means $z = x$, therefore $z \in y$.

For the backward direction:

- Suppose $\{x\} \subseteq y$. Then since $x \in \{x\}$, by the definition of subset, $x \in y$. $\qquad \square$